# How to load a PHP page into a div with jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to write a function that will call `getproduct.php?id=xxx` when clicked.  I can get the `innerHTML` portion to appear, but how do I also call the `php` page that actually does the work?

```
var id = id;
document.getElementById("digital_download").innerHTML = 
    "Downloading...Please be patient. The process can take a few minutes."; 
url = getproduct.php?id=id;
```

Comment: Are you using any jQuery or other JS framework?

Comment: Ugh... wish I had your reply before writing out my answer the long way.  Next time, you should add that type of information in your original post.

Comment: Still doesn't make 'the long way' any less valid, plus you wrote it in a few minutes, so.

Comment: Is it useful to add the tag words into the title, @StevenMoseley? I generally remove them, because I think titles should be short and tags should help with the searching.

Comment: @icedwater - Adding tag words to the title helps people find the Q&A easier on Google.  I always try to make titles match what I would search Google for if I were seeking info on the topic.

Comment: I often err on the conservative side of this discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles/ I like question titles to be specific to the problem and as short as possible so that they can be read in one glance. The top answer on that question suggests to me that results get thrown out correctly even without tag words in the title, and it seems I'm not the only one who thinks that way. Just a side discussion :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery for example.

```
var id = 1;
$('#digital_download').html('Downloading...'); // Show "Downloading..."
// Do an ajax request
$.ajax({
  url: "getproduct.php?id="+id
}).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
  $('#digital_download').html(data); // display data
});
```

Answer (score 15):

you can call or load php page inside a div using this line as :-

```
$("#content_div").load("ajax/page_url.php");
```

the "ajax/page_url.php" its a relative path of php file.

so here you can replace it with external url as well.

please share you knowledge if i am wrong.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the accepted answer. Less code and works.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways by which you can load a page into a division .

The very method is

```
var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('digital_download').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
   xmlhttp.open("GET", 'getproduct.php?id=' + id,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

this is a typical method with no external reference.

If you go with reference then there are 5 ways to make a ajax call with jQuery

---

- **load():** Load a piece of html into a container DOM.
- **jQuery.getJSON():** Load a JSON with GET method.
- **jQuery.getScript():** Load a JavaScript.
- **jQuery.get():** Use this if you want to make a GET call and play extensively with the response.
- **jQuery.post():** Use this if you want to make a POST call and don’t want to load the response to some container DOM.
- **jQuery.ajax():** Use this if you need to do something when XHR fails, or you need to specify ajax options (e.g. cache: true) on the
  fly.

---

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** the original question didn't reference jQuery.  Leaving this answer here as others may find it useful.

Here's how you would do this using the XHR object for an ajax request without jQuery or Prototype or other JS library.

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('digital_download').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", 'getproduct.php?id=' + id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can call the below function to perform this it loads the data from server on success you can create fail function as well

```
 function setValue(Id) {
 document.getElementById("digital_download").innerHTML = 
"Downloading...Please be patient. The process can take a few minutes.";
 var data1 = {
        message: Id,
    };

    $.ajax({
      data: data1,
      type: 'GET',
      url: "http://urltoscript/index.php",
     cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data) {
        console.log("Response for cancel is: " + data);

     document.getElementById("digital_download").innerHTML =  data

      }
    });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get or post request using query

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: data,
success: success,
dataType: dataType
});
```

[example](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)